# Ryzen 5 3600XT graphics performance

Tags: video, graphics-card, graphics, integrated-graphics, amd-ryzen

AMD's website seems to indicate that discrete graphics card is not required for the Ryzen 5 3600 XT. For example, in [here](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-5-3600x), if you scroll to the 'Related Products' section, it says the Ryzen 5 3600 requires a discrete graphics card, but for the Ryzen 5 3600XT it says it does not.

So this seems to indicate it does not require a discrete graphics card. What does this mean about its graphics performance? Can it play modern games at 4K without a graphics card? Or at least 1080P? Can it be used for video editing? Would an video editor like Davinci Resolve use it's GPU cores (if it has any)?

I have not found any benchmarks indicating it's graphics performance. All the benchmarks I've seen couple it with a graphics card.

[edit]
The 3600XT does not have a integrated GPU. AMD's website is just omitting that does not require a discrete graphics card. Their naming convention is also confusing because it reminds of of the RX 5500 XT.

Comment: It has no on-chip graphics. Your opening statement is incorrect. https://uk.pcmag.com/chipsets-processors/127658/amd-ryzen-5-3600xt

Comment: This question is confusing.  According to AMD's [specifications](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-5-3600xt) of the processor, it actually does NOT have a built-in GPU, which means you will need a discrete graphics card.  Please edit your question to clarify, what exactly is your question, because the Ryzen 5 3600XT does NOT have a iGPU.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ok, so that says it does not have a IGPU. But I'm not sure how to explain the possible discrepancy from AMD's own website.

Comment: @Ramhound That does not indicate it doesn't have a IGPU. In fact, it leads me to believe it does have a IGPU because it says under 'Related Products', the 3600X, 3600 require a graphics card, but the page for 3600X says the 3600XT does not require a graphics card.

Comment: It doesn't indicate it doesn't have an IGPU, but neither does it indicate it **does**. Call it an error of omission. If it did have one, they'd be keen to mention it.

Comment: I guess I'm keen on good documentation. That's probably the case. Else, their website also indicates it does not have a fan! I guess the 3600XT really is a waste of money and the 3600 is a better value.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I lost track of who pinged me my apologizes.

Comment: @user2233706 - In this case the absence of it indicating what the the iGPU is exactly is what indicates the discrete graphic card is required.  Understanding that none of the Ryzen 5 (Zen 2) 3xxx processors have an iGPU also helps. [Here](https://www.amd.com/en/processors/ryzen-with-graphics) are the Zen 2 based processors that have a iGPU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XT Ryzen models don’t have iGPU’s.
Only the models with a G suffix have them.
So your question doesn’t make sense.